# Can I Layer JavaFX Controls?

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx

I just had a problem with an invisible, disabled list and a text field(visible) underneath it. I wasn't able to access the text field because I was still clicking on the list. Is there any way to have an invisible control and still be able to use the control underneath it?

Comment: [setMouseTransparent javadoc for nodes.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setMouseTransparent-boolean-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the [StackPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) control. This is easiest to do using the JavaFX scenebuilder.
[This webpage has a topic on StackPanes.](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm)
I am assuming that you just have to fiddle with the StackPane.alignment to change which controls are usable etc. Hope this helps;

FXML:

```
<StackPane id="StackPane" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
      <children>
              <ProgressBar fx:id="" disable="false" prefWidth="294.0" progress="0.0" StackPane.alignment="CENTER" />
              <Slider fx:id="" prefWidth="294.0" style=""  StackPane.alignment="CENTER" />
      </children>
  </StackPane>
```